# Why does U-Boot on Cubox continually reboot with error "** File not found /boot.scr **"?

Tags: boot-loader, arm, u-boot

Having [used dd to write the standard stock Cubox Ignition image](http://wiki.solid-run.com/doku.php?id=products:imx6:overview:flashsdcard) to Micro SD card, I'm finding the Cubox i4pro is continually rebooting, briefly showing these errors.

```
** File not found /boot.scr **
** File not found /uEnv.txt **
```

Steps followed to write this image to Micro SD card, which of course resulted in the File not found errors are:

```
wget http://download.solid-run.com/pub/solidrun/Ignition-imx/20151220/ignition.img
dd if=ignition.img bs=1M of=/dev/sdb
```

Also tried this, but got same (fail) behaviour.

```
wget http://download.solid-run.com/pub/solidrun/Ignition-imx/6-nov-2014/ignition.img
dd if=ignition.img bs=1M of=/dev/sdb
```

The Micro SD card contains the Ignition image, as below:

```
CuBox-i U-Boot > ext2ls mmc 0:1
<DIR>       1024 .
<DIR>       1024 ..
<DIR>     368640 lost+found
           38118 inx6q-hummingboard.dtb
        34687192 zImage
          346871 imx6dl-hummingboard2.dtb
           33218 imx6dl-cubox-i.dtb
           40257 imx6q-hummingboard2.dtb
               0 ignition.sig
           34736 imx6q-cubox-i.dtb
             124 repo.url
           36600 imx6dl-hummingboard.dtb
CuBox-i U-Boot >
```

U-Boot version details are as below

```
Cubox-i U-Boot > version

U-Boot 2013.10-rc4 (Dec 20 2015 - 13:08:16)
arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Buildroot 2014.08-gc7811d0) 4.8.3
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.22
Cubox-i U-Boot >
```

Doesn't seem to be a hardware failure, as [writing a debian image](https://people.debian.org/~gwolf/) to the same Micro SD card results in the Cubox booting ok.  Steps followed to achieve this are as below:

```
wget https://people.debian.org/~gwolf/cubox.img.xz
xz -d cubox.img.xz
dd if=cubox.img of=/dev/sdb
```

**UPDATE 01-Feb-2017** gave up on Ignition and used Armbian, works fine, steps as below.

```
wget https://dl.armbian.com/cubox-i/Debian_jessie_next.7z
7za e Debian_jessie_next.7z
dd if=Armbian_5.25_Cubox-i_Debian_jessie_next_4.9.7.img of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: Did you compile this u-boot? Have you been able to load the zImage and device tree blob into memory from the cli?

Comment: If you can get it to boot by loading zImage and dtb you can create the uEnv.txt file with those values. Does your system require the kernel and dtb to be wrapped in a single file, like uImage?

Comment: @jc just using standard image from Solidrun, question updated to clarify this.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you using [this](http://download.solid-run.com/pub/solidrun/Ignition-imx/20151220/ignition.img) ignition image, or a different one?

Comment: @Dmitry - yes, that is the ignition image used without success.

Comment: I have never used ignition, but as far as I can tell, `boot.scr` and `uEnv.txt` are really missing in this ignition image (so it's not a download/write failure). Very puzzling.

Comment: there are some [instructions here](http://wiki.solid-run.com/doku.php?id=products:imx6:software:development:u-boot) that talk about creating a sample uEnv.txt file and a way to create a boot.scr; have you tried those?

Answer (score -2):

I guess your boot image is bad, its missing boot logo that is `boot.scr`. Create a fresh image or copy missing files from new image to locations.